# Proving divergence of an alternating series with a non-standard function

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

I was given the following equation and told to prove either convergence or divergence. I am sure that it diverges, but I am unsure as to how I would go about proving that mathematically.

$$ \sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-2^k)*1*3*5...(2k+1)}{1*4*7...(3k+1)}\ $$

I used the ratio test as I remember I was supposed to, but I cannot figure out how to cancel the remaining terms out to get a usable answer. Does it leave me with just:

$ \frac{(2)(2k+3)(3k+10)}{(3k+4)(2k+1)}\ $

That seems wrong to me but it's as far as I could go

Comment: Apart from a typo, $3k+10$ instead of $3k+1$, this looks right. What is the limit as $k\to\infty$?

Comment: If i were to do it directly from here, i would end up with infinity over infinity, unless I am able to just say that as k gets larger, it becomes 2

Comment: Divide top and bottom by $k^2$. You will find that the limit is $2$.

Comment: Is that the right way to do it though? The crux of my issue is that the ratio test asks to test the function at the value of the term after k, and divide that by the function at k. In doing that, I am left with something similar to what I mentioned above, but I am not sure if that would allow the terms to cancel.

Comment: @KM529 that's not what it asks you to do. It asks you to calculate the limit as $k \to \infty$ of what you are talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might have a typo, probably the question has $(-2)^k$ rather than $-2^k$. But it does not affect the analysis.
If a series $\sum_{k=0}^n a_k$ is convergent, it is necessarily true that $\lim_{k\rightarrow \infty} a_k = 0$. Note that 
$$
a_k = \frac{(-2)^k*1*3*5...(2k+1)}{1*4*7...(3k+1)}.
$$
The number of terms in the numerator and the denominator are equal to $k+1$ (except $(-2)^k$).
$$
a_k = (-1)^n\frac{1}{2}\frac{2 \times 1}{1}\frac{2 \times 3}{4}\cdots \frac{2 \times (2k+1)}{(3k+1)}.
$$
You can see that the right hand side terms are each greater than 1 except a constant. Moreover, the last term goes to infinity, which implies that the term $a_k$ have two subsequences going to $+\infty$ and $-\infty$. Therefore, this series cannot be convergent.